# Delete automatically post with sidekiq-cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I'm trying to do a cron (with sidekiq-con) on rails to delete all videos uploaded by a user every 20 minutes.
Here is my code:

sidekiq.rb :

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"
    if File.exist?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
    Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
    end
end
```

schedule.yml :

```
clean_video:
  cron: "* * * * *"
  class: "CleanVideoJob"
  queue: default
```

jobs/clean_video_job.rb :

```
class CleanVideoJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    Video.where(['created_at < ?', 20.minutes.ago]).destroy_all
  end
end
```

The job queues up every minute on my sidekiq GUI (localhost: 3000 / sidekiq) but nothing happens. I do not really see my problem .. Thank you

Comment: You say nothing happens. Do you mean the jobs enter the queue but never run, or they are running, but no videos are destroyed?

Comment: Did you run `bundle exec sidekiq` to start the sidekiq workers?

Comment: Yes i see the jobs enter in the queue every minute but they never run. And ofc i have run this command

Comment: Do other kinds of job run successfully? If you pop open a console and run `CleanVideoJob.perform_later` does the job run? It sounds like either sidekiq isn't running or isn't configured as a backend for ActiveJob.

Comment: Also, perhaps it would be easier for you to use the gem "arask". It's much simpler to setup.